# Can a real sequence have every natural number as its limit point?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does there exist a real sequence such that every $n\in\mathbb N$ is its limit point?

I can not get anywhere with this.

Comment: The set of all rational  numbers  arranged in a sequence has every real number as  a limit point.

Comment: Or something like $0,0,1,0,1,2,0,1,2,3,0,\ldots$ - which is $n$ minus the largest triangular number $\le n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this sequence: $$1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,...$$

Answer (score 7):

You can reason as follows:

If we want a single naturals as a limit point, we can use the constant sequence

$$1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,\cdots$$

If we want two naturals as limit points, we can use the alternating sequence

$$1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,\cdots$$

If we want a finite number of naturals as limit points (say $4$), we can use the round-robin sequence

$$1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,\cdots$$

If we want all naturals, we lengthen the round-robin on each round,

$$1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,\cdots$$

---

If you prefer "non-trivial" accumulation points, i.e. such that the integers that are never reached, you can add a perturbation of decreasing amplitude to every term, such as $\dfrac1{n+1}$.